# php problem with mysqli num rows not working

Tags: php, ajax

i have a problem with this functions `mysqli_num_rows()`, because sometimes works well for me, and sometimes it gives me head rush I really don't know whats wrong with it

this is my PHP file:

```
<?php  

    include 'dbh.php';

    function get_font_class() {
        global $conn;
        if ( isset($_POST['dataSearchBox']) ) {
            $searchKeyword = $_POST['dataSearchBox'];
            $sql = ' SELECT * FROM fontawesomeicons WHERE name LIKE ' .$searchKeyword. '%; ';
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            if ( mysqli_num_rows( $result ) > 0 ) {
                while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result ) ) {
                    echo '<i class=' .$row['class']. '></i>';
                }
            } else {
                echo "There Are No Icons At The Moment!";
            }
        }   
    }
    get_font_class();
```

Comment: This is at risk for SQL injection attacks.  Don't use input data directly into queries.  Then explain your actual problem better...

Comment: Your SQL is invalid. Use error reporting. Also you are open to SQL injections, if the syntax is corrected.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use double quotes after and before class atribute

```
    include 'dbh.php';

    function get_font_class() {
        global $conn;
        if ( isset($_POST['dataSearchBox']) ) {
            $searchKeyword = $_POST['dataSearchBox'];
            $sql = ' SELECT * FROM fontawesomeicons WHERE name LIKE ' .$searchKeyword. '%; ';
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            if ( mysqli_num_rows( $result ) > 0 ) {
                while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result ) ) {
                    echo '<i class="' .$row['class']. '"></i>';
                }
            } else {
                echo "There Are No Icons At The Moment!";
            }
        }   
    }
    get_font_class();
```

Answer (score -2):

Write the sql as

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM fontawesomeicons WHERE name LIKE '%".$searchKeyword."%'" ;
```

Comment: Still invalid SQL...and SQL injectable..and you changed the `like`s functionality.

Comment: No this is valid from the user's point of view . His question was not sql injection , his question was to display result on the page .

Comment: `%'` is wrong for opening and `'%` is wrong for closing. Also the leading `%` is possibly too loose and won't allow for indices to be used.

Comment: You still changed the functionality.  %keyword% will match different results than keyword%.  However, I'd prefer we not put a bandaid over bad code anyways.